# Set Java Precision For Calculations

Tags: java, precision

How do we set a specific precision in java for further calculations? For example,if  I need calculations to be done up to 11 precision; How do I set it?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` to have infinite precision.

Comment: If you use `BigDecimal` you can control the precision of all calculations. Unlike what @ifly6 is saying, it cannot actually be infinite (don't have infinite memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not *"set a specific precision in java for further calculations"*.

What you do is choose a numeric format that supports the precision you need and perform your calculations using that format.  `double` has about 15 significant digits of precision, and if you need more (i.e. 11 places to the right of the decimal point regardless of magnitude) then you must use `BigDecimal`, where the precision is limited only by available memory.  Then you truncate to the required precision on output.

Note that `BigDecimal` requires that you specify a precision when the results of an operation can be a repeating decimal (i.e. `1/3`) to avoid trying to create an infinitely long repeating decimal.  You can do this by providing a `RoundingMode` or a `MathContext` to the `divide()` method.

Note that a `MathContext` comes somewhat close to your request, as it encapsulates both the precision and rounding mode.  However it does not apply globally for future calculations, it must be provided on each calculation that it is going to control.